# TFS 2017.3: vNext Run Functional Tests Task has empty dropdown list

Tags: tfs, vnext

our company has a TFS 2017 Update 3 Server behind a loadbalancer with this config:

- loadbalancer is listening on *tfs.company.com* on port 443
- loadbalancer routes pakets to TFS (*10.x.x.x*) on SSL

On the TFS Admin-Console the Server- and Notification-URL are configured as *tfs.company.com*

If we want to configure the vNext Build Task *Run functional tests* we set *Test selection* to *Test Plan*. Normally we could select now the IDs for Testplan and Testsuites which should be executed for testing. This lists are empty...

TFS is querieng his own REST-API to fill the dropdowns. This fails with following errors (fiddler)

[pakets in fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR3IP.jpg)

*7-9: HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication
10-13: Error Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel..","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.ServiceEndpointQueryFailedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi","typeKey":"ServiceEndpointQueryFailedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}*

Our infrastructure team is not able to solve this problem. The problem is not versionspecific. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Is there other issue after setting up SSL? Have you installed the certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on the build agent machine (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer#installing-certificats-build-svrs)? Check Event log in Event Viewer to see whether there are useful messages.

Comment: I think the build agent machine has nothing to do with thast, that's an issue of the THS machine or not? Event log has nothing logged :-/

Comment: Are there other tasks have this issue?